# Unknown Cairo context field when porting to python-gi

Tags: python, gtk3, pycairo, gpsd

I am the maintainer of GPSD. Having learned that the gobject bindings for pygtk are deprecated, I am attempting to forward-port our Python test clients to python-gi. I ported xgps with little difficulty using the pygi-convert.sh [script](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject/IntrospectionPorting) , but am now having a difficulty with xgpsspeed.

After I run pygi-convert.sh on xgpsspeed, I first have to hand-fix the "expose_event" signal, changing it to to "draw".  I expected this, as I had to do the same in the successful xgps port.

Running the patched version throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xgpsspeed", line 72, in draw
    event.area.x,
AttributeError: 'cairo.Context' object has no attribute 'area'
```

which clearly relates to this section of code in the method handler:

```
def draw(self, _unused, event, _empty=None):
    self.cr = self.get_window().cairo_create()
    self.cr.rectangle(
        event.area.x,
        event.area.y,
        event.area.width,
        event.area.height
    )
```

My search-fu is not turning up any obvious reason for the event argument to be passed a Cairo context under 3.x rather than the event it's expecting and got under 2.x.  I can only guess that the handler signature has changed, but I can't find any documentation that addresses the question.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to my own question, for anyone who finds this via Google search.

Yes, the draw method takes a different signature in 3.x.  That signature includes a Cairo context but *not* the Gdk expose event as in 2.x.

I was able to get to the next step by creating a handler for the sizer allocation event:

`def on_size_allocate(self, _unused, allocation):
        self.width = allocation.width
        self.height = allocation.height`

and then writing the rectangle draw as

`self.cr.rectangle(0, 0, self.width, self.height)`

This way I didn't actually need the expose event content any more.

However, inserting 0s for the x,y args was just a guess that the method takes relative coordinates and could be subtly wrong.

The documentation on this stuff is *terrible*.